# Crystal Report for VS2010 Alignment issue

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have this web application that uses crystal reports for VS2010. I have crystal reports service pack 2 installed. What i don't understand is that everything works fine in the development machine however, once i publish my report to the production server, all the textboxes that have more than one word in them are disaligned. I mean, the next word scrolls down. This looks really bad if its a heading row, as the heading start overlapping the details rows.

I understand that it has something to do with the crystal report versions, as suggested in other discussions. However i have checked the crpe32.dll version on this location C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86 and it is 13.0.0.99 in the development machine as well as the production machine. So technically, the version is 13.0.0.99

Here is the page directive of the ASP.NET page that has the crystal report viewer in it.  and presumeably the version i am refering is 13.0.2. I don't know if it is the right way of doing it or not.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"
    Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>
```

but i am not having the headings aligned properly. Can somebody help please?
I should have been like this
[image: Correct Report]

While it shows like this 
[image: INCORRECT REPORT]

Comment: I am NOT a Crystal Reports expert, but is it possible that you have different fonts installed on the two machines?

Comment: no its not about the font. It has something to do with versions, i am sure

Comment: What bands are the values in? it could be that they are overlapping each other.  Otherwise, and probably more likely, it may be the way the fields are being made multi-line: in the original version they are using return/newline as a line separator, but the other version is using return OR newline, doubling each line break.  If that is the case, try splitting them into two fields instead of one with a line break.

Comment: @EvilBob22 yes i think that u r right here, if i split the multi-line text object into two different text objects, it shows fine. say for example. with "Sr. No" where the no. is shown scrolled down, if i break it into two different objects, and write "sr" in one and "No" in second then it should not have any problem. However, i don't think it is the correct way of doing it? isn't it?

Comment: It is just a label, you can make it however you want. The only real difference you should see would be in an export of the report; for example in Excel it would be in two cells instead of one with a line break.